# Does --webpacker=stimulus somehow disable form_with remote:true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, stimulusjs

This may be a wild goose chase. Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5

Case 1:

- Using rails new --webpack=stimulus
- rails generate scaffold Events name:string
- edit the form_with to not have remote:true
- add a format.js to the controller
- create an event

**Unexpected: the client continues to ask for html, that is, it seems like remote:true is still in effect**

Case 2:

- Using rails new without --webpack=stimulus
- rails generate scaffold Events name:string
- edit the form_with to not have remote:true
- add a format.js to the controller
- create an event

**as expected, I get an error because I don't have a create.js.erb**

So, it seems that there might be a connection between webpack=stimulus and the remote behavior of form_with. Without --webpack=stimulus Rails 5.2 form_with behaves as I would expect, and with it, for some reason, the dispatch back to the server when I "submit" asks for html not for javascript, even though remote=true. Could there be a connection?

Answer (score 0):

starting from Rails 5.2 when using `form_with` it is by defaut `remote`. If you want to post your form in `html`format you must specify `local: true`

source 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

> By default form_with attaches the data-remote attribute submitting the form via an XMLHTTPRequest in the background if an Unobtrusive JavaScript driver, like rails-ujs, is used. See the :local option for more.

To answer more specifically your question there is no link between Stimulus and the remote form behavior

Comment: And yet I saw one. That's what I was asking about,,,

Comment: you say `edit the form_with to not have remote:true` but with rails 5.2 the form has `local: true` not sure to understand exactly what you have done?

Comment: In my test doing the same steps as you describe I have removed `local: true` to the form_with. Forms are posted in JS and everything works out of the box without adding format.js as you have rails-ujs and turbolinks enabled by default

Comment: Ah, so I don't need that format.js. That must have been causing the problem then. Thanks!